# Manually transfer WordPress database from domain to another domain with postname in permalink

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I'm new to WordPress.
I needed to transfer a WordPress site from domain to another domain. In addition, the previous WordPress site was in trouble. So I did not have access to the dashboard. So, I decided to install a new WordPress in new host and domain then transfer Data Base. But I forgot to get Premlink out of postname. WordPress pages are not displayed right after import and I have 404 error. please guide me. This is very important to me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions that ask "where do I start?" or "what can I do"  are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a correct answer. Give a good read over [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post with a specific problem you have - ideally presenting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a very common issue. The steps you should take is in the following order:

1. Be sure your server honors the .htaccess file ( /etc/apache2/sites-available/your-domain-probably.conf There should be something like

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/your/path> 
        AllowOverride All 
   </Directory>
   ```
2. Go to your /wp-admin -> settings -> permalinks select your type and then click save even if your type is already selected
3. If the steps above be sure that your web server has privileges to write in your wordpress installation directory. Assuming you use apache2 up until now that would be

   ```
   sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/your/wordpress/directory
   sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/your/wordpress/directory
   ```

   Hope i was helpfull !

Answer (score 0):

In the database, you probably need to update the site url and the home url. You also need to move the wp-content directory.

The answer is here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL